# Canvas: clear rect but keep the rest of the content

Tags: android

I want to draw some text onto my canvas and want to clear everything which was drawn out of a specific area (area defined by a Rect).

[image]

I draw the magenta-Text and want to clear everything in the grey and keep everything in the white box. I got the white area as a rect.

Comment: You can use the drawRect method from the canvas object.

Comment: I do NOT want to draw over it, i want to earse it

Comment: whats the difference from erasing and drawing over it with a color of your choice? simply call drawRect 4 times to clear the area outside the white rectangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. draw four rectangles with paint set to white color.

- mCanvas  - Object of android.graphics.Canvas
- rect     - Rect
- xMax     - Maximus X value
- yMax     - Maximus Y value

  `mCanvas.drawRect(0, 0, rect.left, yMax, paint);`

  `mCanvas.drawRect(0, 0, xMax, rect.top, paint);`

  `mCanvas.drawRect(0, rect.bottom, xMax, yMax, paint);`

  `mCanvas.drawRect(rect.right, 0, xMax, yMax, paint);`

It might help u

Answer (score 2):

For paint with transparency use:

```
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, rect.left, yMax, paint);
    canvas.drawRect(rect.left, 0, xMax, rect.top, paint);
    canvas.drawRect(rect.left, rect.bottom, rect.right, yMax, paint);
    canvas.drawRect(rect.right, rect.top, xMax, yMax, paint);
```

Or if you need another shape use Path:

```
    Path path = new Path();
    //path.addCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, Path.Direction.CCW);
    path.addRect(rect, Path.Direction.CCW);

    canvas.clipPath(path, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, xMax, yMax, paint);
```

Unfortunately clipPath works only from API 18 (if hardware acceleration enabled)